# Growing slower than exponential?

Tags: analysis

Consider $2^{cn}+a(n)$ with $c$ being an exponential growth rate.

Am I right that 
$$
2^{cn}+a(n)\sim 2^{cn}
$$
only, if $a(n)$ grows slower than exponential?

And if yes.. when does $a(n)$ grow slower than exponential?

Comment: Even if $a(n) = 2^{dn}$, it can be asymptotically less than $2^{cn}$ if $d < c$, and $2^{cn} + a(n) \sim 2^{cn}$

Comment: If $a(n)$ is an (increasing) sequence of real numbers, isn't $2^{cn}+a(n)\sim 2^{cn}$ always fullfilled?

Comment: Of course not, it depends on the asymptotic behavior of $a(n)$. For example, if $a(n) = 2^{n^2}$, then $2^{cn} + a(n) \sim a(n)$, provided that $c$ is constant.